# kendo grid works fine when javaScript alert exist but not working without javaScript alert

Tags: user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

When I add a new row kendo ui grid it does not move to next page even I set page number dynamically.
But when there is a javaScrip alert it's working fine.
Has any one faced this issue before. Please suggest me a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "When I add a new row kendo ui grid it does not move to next page"? Why should it move to the next page? These kind of problems use to happen because timing of things happening in parallel. What alert does is make one of them wait and that allows the second to complete

Comment: Thank you for your response ,                                        I have done few things which kendo does not support straight away, persisting user selection and select currently added row on grid refresh (load last page of the grid) and select most recent row
Problem is, for example assume I'm in page 2 in the grid and I have 5 rows currently (page size = 5) now when I add next row and set the page number to 3 dynamically on grid refresh it does not move to page 3 when the alert is not there. But when alert is there it’s move to next page (3) and select the currently added row.

Comment: That's right! When you add a new row it takes some time to be created (it is an asynchronous task) when you do the alert you are actually delaying the next action and then it has time to have it created and therefore you can more to page 3.

Comment: Yes, but would it be possible for me to wait without having an alert() 
I think waiting for Editing_Read() (in Controller) to retun is the problem.

Comment: Yes! Do `setTimeout(function() { grid.page(3); }, 500);` This wait half second (500ms) and then invoke `grid.page(3)`. Is this enough?

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as answer so other people will find it easily :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you add a new row there are a series of actions that happen in parallel and they are not immediate. If you try to move to the end but the row still is being created, if fails.

When you add an alert, you delay the fact of moving and creation now have time.

If you really need to do it, you can add a timeout (delay) it is not nice/clean but should work.

Do something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    grid.page(3);
}, 500);
```

for introducing half second (500 ms) delay, should be enough.

Comment: Can we configure Kendo grid data source to be Synchronous 

      .DataSource(dataSource =>
               dataSource.Ajax()

      .Model(model =>
        {
      .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")))
      .......


      $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

Is this is an Ajax Asynchronous call. If so can we make this call to a Synchronous call.
Please suggest me a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: It is an ajax asynchronous call and as far as I know you cannot make it synchronous. You might program a `read` function that does a synchronous request but your call will get blocked waiting for it and maybe the user experience is not going to be _nice_.

Comment: Yes, thank you @OnaBai, I achieved the functionality I wanted using delay technique and Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

We had sort of similar issue in IE - onchange fired twice with alert in the event handler. According to what you saying, it sounds like when the alert is NOT in you are getting correct behaviour. Review your code without having the alert in or post a fiddle. Below is an answer from Kendo support in regards to alerts while debugging. Do not use alerts with kendo to stay safe.

Basically this behavior is caused by using "alert" method for debugging purposes - please note that this is not recommended because it can lead to unexpected behavior when interacting with focusing elements. After replacing the "alert" method and with "debbuger" command or "console.log()" function the change event is working as expected - please check this screencast(http://screencast.com/t/7qIAdK6hZ5kD).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in my case it's works fine when alert() is there

Comment: Share a fiddle, I am really interested in how alert helps to Kendo grid flipping a page. Assume that alert in not supposed to be there, because it causes problems and that there is fair amount of kendo grids out there what are changing pages without alert just fine, at least I have few.